# XSLT select only first node in repeated nested tree

Tags: xslt-1.0

Some XML that represents the hierarchy rules of an archive, a short sample:

```
<someXML>
  <dependency-rules>
    <name>FONDS
      <dependency-rules>
        <name>CATEGORY</name>
      </dependency-rules>
    </name>
  </dependency-rules>
</someXML>
```

Desired output should reflect the hierarchy, like this

```
FONDS
  CATEGORY
```

The indentation means that a FONDS can have CATEGORYs. I'm struggling with the nested repeated dependency-rules/name construction. This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//name" />
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name" >
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::dependency-rules)" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces this, which is wrong:

```
1   FONDS CATEGORY
2   CATEGORY
```

of course it matches on *every* `<name>` in each level. How can I get *only* the first name in each `<dependency-rules>` node? I can't seem to find the right words to google for to get a similar example. The solution is probably very easy, but for me, hard to find.

XSLT 1.0 solution preferred, but not vital.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **exact** output you expect to get (if you want to get an HTML table, then show the exact HTML code).

Comment: Thanks, but the exact *desired* output is the text shown. There's no particular need for an HTML-table. To put it bluntly, I don't care _how_ it's done, as long as it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XSLT attempts to create an HTML table, which is not well-suited to display a hierarchical structure such as your XML. If you want the result to be an HTM document, I think you might be better off using an unordered list instead. This would be very easy to generate:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/someXML">
    <html>
        <body>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="dependency-rules"/>
            </ul>
        </body> 
    </html> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dependency-rules">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(name/text())"/>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="name/dependency-rules"/>
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using your input example, the result would be:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>FONDS
            <ul>
               <li>CATEGORY
                  <ul></ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

and a browser would display this as:

[image]

If you like, you can make it more pretty by adding some CSS.

---

**P.S.** If you're happy with a text result, you could reduce the code to only this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="dependency-rules">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(name/text())"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="name/dependency-rules">
        <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="concat($indent, '&#9;')"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice recursion too, I didn't know one could do this. In reality things are a bit more complicated, but that will be a different question - if I can't work it out with your example.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get only the first name in each  node?

You could simply replace your instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="." />
```

with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text()" />
```

At the same time you could simplify your entire attempt to just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <xsl:for-each select="//name">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::dependency-rules)" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, that doesn't get you any closer to your desired goal of representing the hierarchy by indentation. For this purpose, an unordered list as suggested by y.arazim would be much better.

Answer (score -3):

To achieve the desired output, you can modify your XSLT stylesheet as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//name[not(ancestor::name)]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:param name="indent" select="''"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::dependency-rules">
      <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="concat($indent, '  ')"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dependency-rules">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name">
      <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="$indent"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet uses recursive templates to traverse the XML hierarchy and generate the desired output with proper indentation. It starts by selecting the top-level `name` elements that don't have an ancestor `name`, and then applies templates recursively to the `dependency-rules` elements, passing the updated indent value.

The output is produced using the `<xsl:output method="text"/>` declaration, which ensures that the result is plain text rather than HTML.

With the given input XML, the output will be:

```
FONDS
  CATEGORY
```

The stylesheet generates the expected hierarchical structure by correctly handling the nested `dependency-rules` and selecting only the first `name` within each level.

Comment: I attempted to run your XSLT and got stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Your last three answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: `<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::dependency-rules">` wil  apply  all ancestor's . Therefore the  infinite loop.